# Collection view selection and DidDeselect issue

Tags: swift, collectionview

I'm trying to change cell text font on didSelect and DidDeselect delegate of the collection view, but it isn't working fine. Initially, I want my first cell text font to be bold and when the user taps any other cell it should change that tapped cell font and remaining cell come back to original font. This is my code,

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let balanceData = balanceArray[indexPath.row]
    self.recentTransactionArray.removeAll()
    let selectedCell = currencyCVC.cellForItem(at: indexPath)  as? CurrencyCVC
    //self.index = indexPath

    if indexPath != self.index
    {
        selectedCell?.amountLbl.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize:18, weight: .bold)
        selectedCell?.currencyLbl.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize:22, weight: .bold)
        selectedCell?.availableBalanceLbl.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize:11, weight: .bold)
        selectedCell?.depositLbl.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize:11, weight: .bold)
    }
    else
    {
        selectedCell?.amountLbl.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize:18, weight: .medium)
        selectedCell?.currencyLbl.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize:22, weight: .regular)
        selectedCell?.availableBalanceLbl.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize:11, weight: .medium)
        selectedCell?.depositLbl.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize:11, weight: .medium)
    }
}
```

This is my DidDeselect delegate,

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CurrencyCVC else {
        return
    }

    if indexPath != self.index
    {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            cell.amountLbl.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize:18, weight: .medium)
            cell.currencyLbl.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize:22, weight: .regular)
            cell.availableBalanceLbl.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize:11, weight: .medium)
            cell.depositLbl.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize:11, weight: .medium)
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I tap any cell it changes current cell font but remaining cell font doesn't change to original font. How i can do that?

Comment: did you confirmed your collection view with the delegate? collectionView.delegate = self

Comment: yes, i have mention it. @ZeeshanAhmed

Comment: right, in my projects i place a specific var in my datasource model like 'isSelected' & then in cellForRow fun i configure my styling for both cases...
Then in didSelect method i only change that bool value & reload the collectionView

Comment: i didn't got the point can explain through code? @ZeeshanAhmed

Comment: okay i posting some code for you

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following logic its pretty simple to execute

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.title.text = arrData[indexPath.item].name

    //  setting different fonts when cell is selected & when unselected
    cell.title.font = arrData[indexPath.item].isSelected ? UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15) : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 13)
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    //  here setting all other selections false
    arrData = arrData.compactMap{ return myModel(name: $0.name, isSelected: false) }

    //  then setting selected cell bit true
    arrData[indexPath.row].isSelected = true

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```